# Fixing two user groups with the same ID

Tags: macos, command-line, user-account, accounts, group

Suddenly, my home directory is in the group `messagebus` instead of the usual `staff`.
(I blame texlive for this, but have no evidence.)

The problem is that both groups have the same ID:

```
$ dscl . -read /Groups/staff
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF00000014
GroupMembers: FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000
GroupMembership: root
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: 20
RealName: Staff
RecordName: staff BUILTIN\Users
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Groups
SMBSID: S-1-5-32-545

$ dscl . -read /Groups/messagebus
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: CF898A47-EA83-4E18-AE17-C05E56FBC550
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: 20
RealName: messagebus
RecordName: messagebus
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Groups
```

**What is the safe way to get rid of the `messagebus` group (or give it a different ID)?**

“Safe” here meaning of course that I don't damage my `staff`group.

Comment: I just ran into the exact same problem. What's texlive though? I'm not sure I have it. I'm running OS X Mavericks.

Comment: texlive is a program suite for editing TeX/LaTeX documents. If you're unsure, then you probably don't have it. And maybe I blamed the wrong piece of software then :-)

Comment: In that case, I suspect the problem is caused by a recent (automatic) OS X update? Perhaps the Remote Desktop Client 3.7.1 (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6045), as that seems to be the latest update applied to my machine before I noticed the problem.

Comment: Possible, but then I'd expect more people to have the problem. It seems rather rare.

Comment: This happened to me. I think most users just aren't that observant of their file groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the find command (and save the output listing. This may take a while)

*find / -group messagebus -print*

to ensure that ownership for files can be corrected later with a *chgrp* command.

The following be used

*dscl . -change /Groups/messagebus PrimaryGroupID 20 10000*

Comment: How would finddifferentiate between staff and messafebus, doesn;t it use the gid to find a group?

Comment: The directory where the file resides as shown by *find* should help identify what it's group should be. For example, if there is a file in /Users/xxx it should belong to *staff* but if it is in /Applications then it can stay *messagebus*. A Time Capsule backup can also help, if available.

Comment: but the data stored on the file is the gid ie 20 in both cases (or does HFS do somthing differnt to other Unix file systems)

Comment: Thanks, the `dcsl` command was exactly what I was looking for. After a restart, the groups show up correctly as `staff`. @Mark was right though; the `find` did show all files with gid 20, so this were basically all my home files. No way to distinguish between them and the files that should actually have been in the `messagebus` group.